# Facebook API get User post quantity

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

So I want to get a count of post a user has submitted.  I don't care about the data in the post.  I just want a count of number of posts.

I know that everything in the Facebook API that requests the /feed or /posts data requires the 'read_stream' permission.

I'm wondering if there is an avenue in which I can get the count of posts without needing the read_stream permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you want a count, and in the next sentence you say you want a list...

Either way is not possible, the first one because the Graph API doesn't give you counts, you have to count the entries yourself. Second, for the list of `Posts`, you'll definitely need to `read_stream` permission...

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/feed/#readperms

Comment: That was just poor typing. I edited it.  Thanks for the clarity.  And thank you for confirming my need for the read_stream permission.